# maven multiple level inheritance exclusion

Tags: java, maven

Say, I have this project that has 3 levels -- project, group and module. And I have pom.xml on each level: on project level, I have the dependencies across the whole project, and on group level I have the dependencies shared within the group, and module level has dependencies specific for the group. And I organize the pom file in such way: project pom (is the parent of) group pom (is the parent of) module pom.

project pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>project</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>project</name> 
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.framework1</groupId>
                <artifactId>depend1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>         
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.framework2</groupId>
                <artifactId>depend2</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>         
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.framework3</groupId>
                <artifactId>depend3</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>         
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Say, I have group1 which would need to have dependencies depend1 and depend2 but not depend3.

group1 pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>       
</parent> 
    
<groupId>com.example.project</groupId>
<artifactId>group1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>group1</name> 
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.framework1</groupId>
        <artifactId>depend1</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.framework2</groupId>
        <artifactId>depend2</artifactId>                        
    </dependency>             
<dependencies>
```

And under group1, module1 would need both depend1 and depend2. So it would simply inherit it from group1 pom and no need to specify them.

module1 pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>group1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>       
</parent> 
    
<groupId>com.example.project.group1</groupId>
<artifactId>module1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>module1</name>
```

But for module2, it only needs depend1 but not depend2. How should I specify the exclusion? I have tried a couple of ways but none of them work. For example, I put the group1 dependencies inside a **dependencyManagement** tag but getting some maven error complaining about missing versions. And I have also made the module1 pom inherit from the project pom rather than the group1 pom, it seems work but that kinda breaks the intended structure. Any idea that I could implement this exclusion while preserve the project structure (in maven's perspective)?

module2 pom

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>group1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>       
</parent> 
    
<groupId>com.example.project.group1</groupId>
<artifactId>module2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>module2</name> 

//how to include depend1 but exclude depend2?
```

Comment: I simply suggest not to inherit the dependencies only define the dependencies in the appropriate module.

Comment: @khmarbaise Why that? That's what inheritance is for: to prevent duplication of declarations, isn't it?

Comment: It violates the principle of separation of concerns as in Java itself. Inheritance is not to prevent duplication. The same as in Java

Comment: @khmarbaise I tend to disagree. WP too: "[Inheritance allows programmers \[...\] to reuse code \[...\].](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_\(object-oriented_programming\))". Oracle/Sun too: "[**Inheritance** \[...\] In doing this, you can reuse the fields and methods of the existing class without having to write (and debug!) them yourself.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)".

Comment: @Khmarbaise besides preventing duplication, it also serves a very practical purpose that you can see all the dependencies of your project in a centralized place.

Comment: @fangtasticmrZ If the dependencies are distributed over several levels of inheritance there is no central place to look at... That is not the case for Maven pom's  nor for Java classes. Furthermore duplication is not a bad thing in general...

Comment: @GeroldBroser Creating inheritance based on code reuse is simply a design flaw and a misunderstanding of what object oriented programming is.

Comment: @khmarbaise OT: BTW, the _Apache Maven PMC Member_ link in your SO profile results in _Page Not Found_. And the _Committer on:_ links on your _Apache committer and project index_ page result in _Could not find unix group: ..._.

Comment: @khmarbaise Well, I think the misunderstanding is on your side (or maybe we just talk past each other) but I'm the last to refuse to learn and rethink. Can you please link some references that support your POV. However, I think I see your point: have a project's configuration directly in a project's POM to be able to see it at first sight when looking at the POM. Well, that's also not the case with default goal bindings, with `<dependencyManagement>` in a parent POM etc. and there's `help:effective-pom` and Effective POM in Eclipse's POM Editor, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your dependencies as follows:

```xml
project
  +- pom.xml ... <dependencyManagement>
  +- group1
     +- pom.xml ... <dependency>depend1
     +- module1
     |  +- pom.xml ... <dependency>depend2; <dependency>depend1 inherited from group1
     +- module2
        +- pom.xml ... no <dependency> declared; <dependency>depend1 inherited from group1
```